# How can I make branches track only themselves?

Tags: git

Firstly, apologies if I’ve worded my question completely wrong, but hopefully this extension should clear anything up.

I use Git daily, and have done for about 18 months now. I’m getting a lot more confident with things like branching, merging, rebasing etc, but one of the seemingly more fundamental aspects has passed me by…

**How can I ensure that any branch I work on pushes and pulls only between the remote and local versions of itself?**

I thought I had this nailed, with [this in my `.gitconfig`](https://github.com/csswizardry/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig#L32-L33).

That seems to honour a push just fine… I did actually try creating a corresponding [pull] setting, but running the following workflow gave me the old ‘You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you want to merge with…’ error. The workflow I mentioned was:

1. Checkout my fully up-to-date local master branch.
2. Create a branch off of that called `try/responsive` (`git checkout -b try/responsive`)
3. Do some work, `git push` (no problems here).
4. Someone else pushed to the remote `try/responsive` branch.
5. I run a simple `git pull` and I get that error.

Now, I understand that I could run `git pull origin try/responsive`, but my questions is this:

- How does Git work by default? What tracks what and why? What other options are there?
- How can I set my global config so that push and pull only work between local and remote versions of the same branch?

Apologies if I missed any information, and if I made that longer than I needed to. I’d really appreciate any advice on this :)

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply issue the git push command with the parameter -u (git push -u).
When you do this, your local branch will be setup to track the respective remote branch.

By default, git pull only works, when your local branch is setup to track some remote branch. This will occur e.g. if you issue the above command, or if you create a local branch based on a remote tracking branch. If you create a branch based on a local branch, then no tracking is configured. You can also track a branch that has another name on the remote than your local branch, and i don't know of any possibility to restrict this.

Comment: Worked a treat, and makes perfect sense! I work in an environment where I typically never have to create my own branches (they’re done by the people who write the stories/tasks) so it explains why I’ve never known about `-u`. Thanks so much :)